# Can Someone Explain Why With PHP You Cannot Have A Form Inside Another Forms Processing Logic?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I noticed when building a custom plugin for WordPress - I could not have a form nested within another form.

For example,

```
?>
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="get_new_user" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['get_new_user'])) {
    var_dump("Submit Successful");}
```

So this works - when the form "get_new_user" is submitted the message "Submit Successful" outputs.

But when I nest a form inside a form - it does not work.

For example:

```
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="get_new_user" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php

if (isset($_POST['get_new_user'])) {
    var_dump("Submit Successful");
    ?>

    <form method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="1"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_sensitive_data" value="Save Info" />
    </form>
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit_sensitive_data'])) {
        var_dump("Second Submit Successful");}}
```

This nested form submit - does not work - the second var_dump message "Second Submit Successful" is never triggered and I receive an error message in the debug.log of:

```
rtrim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated..
```

Now when I move the second form outside the if statement like this:

```
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="get_new_user" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php

   if (isset($_POST['get_new_user'])) {
       var_dump("Submit Successful");}

    ?>

    <form method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="1"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_sensitive_data" value="Save Info" />
    </form>
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit_sensitive_data'])) {
        var_dump("Second Submit Successful");}
```

Since it's outside the if statement - the second message outputs and I don't receive an error message.

Can someone explain why with modern programming something like this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your logic renders/processes the secondary form when `get_new_user` is present, if its not present, it doesn't go into your IF statement. perhaps you need `if (isset($_POST['get_new_user']) or isset($_POST['submit_sensitive_data']))`, but realistically, your design needs improvement, there's no need to nest your secondary processing logic inside of the first condition. Your secondary form POST doesn't have the `get_new_user` value, hence why the code isn't reached.

---

Since you're going "deeper" into the form flow, bump the detection of your secondary form submit before the primary...

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit_sensitive_data'])) {

    var_dump("Second Submit Successful");}

elseif (isset($_POST['get_new_user'])) {

    var_dump("First Submit Successful");}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="number" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_sensitive_data" value="Save Info" />
</form>

<?php } else { ?>

First Form / Default State

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="get_new_user" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php }
```

Comment: So the logic here is the else statement (since no other states are met) is the default - so this first form will appear to the end user. Once the first form get_new_user is submitted - the else if fires, and so on. Technically you could have swapped the if and else if and it would still work correctly. The main point here is the else statement is the default state. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you could swap the `if` and `else if` condition and content since each form has its own unique identifying submit button value, and then yes, the `else` is the default state when no post data is present.